# "No such module" when archiving

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, archive

I am having a problem when archiving an iOS app.

On this line of code:

```
import Parse
```

I get this error message:

```
No such module 'Parse'
```

The issue only appears when archiving, otherwhise the app compiles builds and runs with no problem.

The Podfile contains this line:
  pod 'Parse'
and all works well before archiving.

I found what seems to be (at least) a temporary solution.
In the `Build Settings`, if I set the `Build Active Architecture Only` to `Yes`, then it works.

But I doubt that it is good for a long term solution.

Anyone has a better way to recommend?

One question, just to be safe:
What does "Active Architecture" exactly refers to in the expression `Build Active Architecture Only`?

Comment: Active Architectures refers to the selected target device. E.g. if you're building for a simulator it will only build for `arm64`, or if building for a specific device it'll build for `armv7` or `armv7s`.

Comment: Thanks for the information. So when shipping an app for the appStore I guess it is better to set "Build Active Architecture Only" to NO. Though I suppose it is not a big deal if the result does not run on a simulator. As long as it run on all the devices. Am I right?

Comment: That should be fine. I imagine that if there's anything wrong with binary you upload to the App Store then Apple will complain at you to fix it :)